# Play 2.0 templating - working with a string and then presenting it as HTML

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

In Play 2.0, with Scala, I want to make a factory that takes an html fragment and puts every line inside a `<div>` block. I have tried several ways that I can think of but it always comes up either with a type error of String/Html or with the html code being written on the page as if it was text. Does anyone know how to do this?

**UPDATE:**

what I would like to see is something like this:

```
@factories.f_div_lines {
   <a href="/aabbcc"> abc </a>
   <a href="/ccbbdd"> cbd </a>
   <a href="/bbddee"> bde </a>
   <a href="/ddeeff"> def </a>
   <a href="/eeffgg"> efg </a>
}
```

and all the `<a href>` tags would be surrounded by `<div>`'s

Comment: I retagged your question as `playframework-2.0` because you used `playback` :P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you mean to split a multiline String across different `div`s, then write a template like this:

```
@(message: String)

@for(line <- message.lines) {
  <div>@line</div>
}
```

Play automatically escapes HTML contents, so if your `message` contains any you must disable the escaping via a call to `Html`, eg inside your loop

```
<div>@Html(line)</div>
```

and invoke it this way:

```
Ok(views.html.index("First\nSecond\nThird"))
```

See the [Play guide](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/ScalaTemplates) at the section **Iterating**

**UPDATE**
The following code defines `split_lines_in_divs` which accept a `Html` parameter, converts it to a `String` object and applies the same code as above. Note that I used Play's `main` function which is automatically generated by Play! when you create a new Scala project to provide the common HTML pieces

```
@(message: String)

@split_lines_in_divs(the_html: Html) = {
  @for(line <- the_html.toString().lines) {
    <div>@Html(line)</div>
  }
}

@main("The title"){ 

  @split_lines_in_divs {
    <a href="test">Test</a>
    <a href="test2">Test2</a>
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, that works for string that does not contain html. I get the `type mismatch; found : play.api.templates.Html required: String` error on line like `@factories.f_div_lines {"<a href=''>News</a>"}` - even if I escape the `'` characters. What I would really like to get, I describe in the update to the original post.

Comment: Hits the spot! Thank you!!! The combo-lang is a bit confusing for me as a beginner)))

Comment: Also, from your comment I guess that you don't get the point of the new Scala template engine: to be type safe :) Your code didn't fail because it contained HTML tags, it failed because the parameter was an [`Html` object](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0/scala/index.html#play.api.templates.Html), instead it expected a `String`

Comment: Not quite like that - I am comming from Java and Scala world of strict typization, so I understand what you are talking about, but I have very little experience with web and combo-langs and do know almost nothing about Play's classes)))